# input function of python is not working in visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio code for learning python, but I am unable to use the input function (in python). All other functions work properly. I am using python 3.9.2 and I have also installed the python extension in my VS Code. [Here is an image of my code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0rzb.png)

I face that problem only when I use input function; otherwise it works properly.
This problem occurred only in Visual Studio Code, while if I work on Python champ the same code works properly.

Comment: It is working. Only you have an extra space between all statements. Python gives importance to indentations. So, remove that extra space.

Comment: You should put the code into the question vs in an image. But from what I can see in the image, you have your code improperly indented on line 1. I have added a properly spaced answer with code below.

Comment: Correct indentation first, and still if this happens, then here is the solution:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Si8rN5J249M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you installed code runner extension.
you can add this to *settings.json*

```
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
```

or you can disable code-runner, maybe it will work for you.

Comment: I already  installed code runner extension. but I don't  know how to set
 "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,

Comment: on the bottom left of vscode, there has a setting button.Click it 
 and select *settings*, on the Upper right corner has a button *open settings(JSON)*, click and enter it.or as @Sam Varghese, you can watch vedio.

Answer (score 0):

> 

**i am faceing the same problem so i diseble the code runner extention and my problem was s**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).